# Can't find database in Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql-server-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-server

I have SQL Server 2008 and Visual Studio 2010. I install Crystal Report XI and it's fine. I can see that I can have it in my Visual Studio and in toolbox as well.

But the problem start when I want to connect database to Crystal Report. I tried everything means I check server name, all possibility of server name. I got .\SQLEXPRESS server. So when I make new connection using OLE DB and choosing provider for SQL Server, it's asking me to type server name, and user id, password, database.

So I am using integrated login as I am, but there is no server popping down. So I am putting .\sqlexpress but in database field I can't see my database, I can see is those 4 database like master, model, etc. I checked for this problem all over internet but there is no solution.